# How to write rostests using Python under catkin?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/unittest) page gives excellent instructions for on how to write and run unit tests for ROS using Python.  The trouble is, it is 3 years old and only covers rosbuild, not catkin.

I have seen the [docs for catkin_add_nosetests](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-add-nosetests) but that doesn't describe interactions with rostest.

Maybe it is as simple as add_rostest() with a test-launch file that includes a python test program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67387/how-to-write-rostests-using-python-under-catkin?/) by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1351 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-15**:
Here's a small combined rostest and Python example that seems to work: https://github.com/jack-oquin/camera_info_manager_py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the nice doc @joq is volunteering on, there's also a [section about testing](http://farnsworth.csres.utexas.edu/docs/catkin/html/howto/python_nose_configuration.html) that includes `rostest` integration.

---

Update) Now looks like the same documentation (?) has been integrated into the official doc (for [Hydro](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-15**:
Thanks for the testimonial, Isaac. I do still need to add more examples for the complex interactions of rostest with gtest and nosetest.